# ActionBarSherlock static attachment menu

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I want to have a toolbar-like menu at the bottom of an activity, and I'm using ActionBarSherlock in my app, and I found the "Static attachment"-demo that adds a "toolbar" at the bottom...

So I've tried to implement this like below:

```
public class ReadMailInbox extends Activity implements OnCreateOptionsMenuListener 
{
    ActionBarSherlock mSherlock = ActionBarSherlock.wrap(this);

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mSherlock.setContentView(R.layout.readmessage_layout);      
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
        return mSherlock.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        menu.add("Refresh")
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_rotate)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
        return true;
    }
}
```

But it appears at the top of the view instead of at the bottom...

Additionally, I would like to use an xml layout for the menu, instead of adding each menu button, since I want to use this for several activities...

So how I can get it to show at the bottom instead???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use `splitActionBarWhenNarrow` option in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

   ```
   <activity android:name=".YourActivity" android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
   ```
2. Override `onCreateOptionsMenu` as following:

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       final MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_home, menu);

       return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
   }
   ```

Comment: FYI this is not only available via static attachment, you can use it with the regular base activities just the same.

Comment: @JakeWharton is it possible Action bar menu  along with static attachment ?